# golang beego framework некоректно работает пример шаблонизатора

Tags: golang, beego

Зашел на сайт beego документации, [Views -> Template Parsing](https://beego.me/docs/mvc/view/view.md#another-approach), раздел "Another Aproach", пытаюсь сделать пример из этого раздела.
Создал новый проект с помощью bee tool.
Что бы не создавать новый controller и router изменил существующий по умолчанию.
Файл controller/default.go:

```
package controllers

import (
    "github.com/astaxie/beego"
)

type MainController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

func (this *MainController) Get() {
    this.TplName = "blog/add.tpl"
    this.Data["SomeVar"] = "SomeValue"
    this.Data["Title"] = "Add"
}
```

Файл views/blog/add.tpl:

```
{{ template "layout_blog.tpl" . }}
{{ define "css" }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/current.css">
{{ end}}


{{ define "content" }}
    <h2>{{ .Title }}</h2>
    <p> This is SomeVar: {{ .SomeVar }}</p>
{{ end }}

{{ define "js" }}
<script src="/static/js/current.js"></script>
{{ end}}
```

Файл views/layout_blog.tpl:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lin Li</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
 {{ block "css" . }}{{ end }}
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    {{ block "content" . }}{{ end }}
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 {{ block "js" . }}{{ end }}
</body>
</html>
```

Вообщем сделал все как указано в примере, но когда запустил то ничего не отображалось, отображается через промежутки обновления страницы (нужно обновлять страницу несколько раз, что бы увидеть результат). Проблема в "{{define}}" и "{{block}}" шаблона, не так работают... Это только у меня так или я что-то не так сделал?

Для наглядности записал 2 минутный ролик: https://www.screencast.com/t/tjAEAtoT

Comment: Похоже на ошибку BeeGo. Попробуйте скомпилировать проект с `-race` и посмотреть, нет ли гонок. Ну и небольшой совет: начинать изучение веб-приложений на го лучше со стандартной библиотеки, а не с фреймворков.

Comment: Я вот не пойму, чем не устраивает дефолтный шаблонизатор. Он прекрасен, там есть все что нужно для разработки. Зачем юзать beego, трешовый фреймворк с ужасно медленным мультиплексором. https://github.com/spouk/spoukfw/blob/master/spoukrender.go  вот мой пример реализации собственного рендера с перезагрузкой из стандартного шаблонизатора с собственными фильтрами, для собственного фреймворка ( писал для проверки собственных силенок в этом аспекте ).

Comment: И еще, если все же думаешь использовать фреймворк то используй Echo. https://echo.labstack.com/ его реализация мултиплексора на radix tree хороша для средний и мелких проектов и все остальное в порядке по части реализации.

Comment: @Spouk На первый взгляд Echo это копипаст [Gin framework](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/)

Comment: @Spouk У beego все нормально со скоростью, да beego.Router() медленный, но beego.Get() практически не уступает httpRouter который лежит у вас в spouk, гляньте как написан ваш SessionSpouk файл и как реализованы(написаны) сессии в beego... Да и вообще полистал файлы beego и могу сказать, что мне нравится как он написан...